# Entity Framework 6.0 stored procedure returns different number of columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using Entity Framework 6.0. I have stored procedure which return 4 columns:

```
 result, message, id, name
```

If during execution of the stored procedure an error happened, the code will return in the result column and the number of columns in the result set will be only two:

```
result, message
```

But if the stored procedure finishes successfully, it will return N number of records and result set will contain four columns:

```
result, message, id, name
```

And if stored procedure returns two columns I'm getting an exception:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified ...

I understand what this exception means and why it is throwing but I can't understand how to solve this problem. Well, one solution is to create my own type with nullable fields and call `Database.SqlQuery<MyType>`.

Is there any more beautiful solutions? Maybe where is a way to change some settings or to modify something a little and to call my stored procedure as usual?

Comment: Why make it so hard? Can't you just return default values (or others) for `id` and `name` when an error occurs?

Comment: @DionV. have no access to database and db developers will not do any changes